# Thoughts on different types of inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, vtable, virtual-destructor

In looking at the following simple code does it make sense to introduce a virtual destructor if I know that we are not deleting from a base pointer? It seems that we should try to avoid vtable look ups if possible for performance reasons. I understand about premature optimization etc. but this is just a question in general. I was wondering your thoughts on the following:

- using a protected destructor if we are not deleting items through a base pointer
- the overhead associated with introducing a single virtual method

Also, if my class only has the destructor as the virtual method would the lookup overhead only be for the destructor method and other methods would not incur a penalty or once you introduce a vptr everything suffers? I am assuming that each class would have an extra vptr inside of it but that it would only have to perform vptr lookups on the destructor.

```
class CardPlayer
{
  public:
    typedef std::vector<CardPlayer> CollectionType;

    explicit CardPlayer()=default;

    explicit CardPlayer(const Card::CollectionType& cards);
    explicit CardPlayer(Card::CollectionType&& cards);

    void receiveCard(const Card& card);

    bool discardCard(Card&& card);
    void foldCards();

    inline const Card::CollectionType& getCards()  { return cards_; }
    // virtual ~CardPlayer() = default;  // should we introduce vtable if not really needed?
  protected:
    ~CardPlayer()=default;
    Card::CollectionType cards_;
};
--------------------------------------------------------------------
#include "CardPlayer.h"
#include <functional>

class BlackJackPlayer : public CardPlayer
{
  public:
    typedef std::vector<BlackJackPlayer> CollectionType;
    typedef std::function<bool(const Card::CollectionType&)> hitFnType;

  BlackJackPlayer(hitFnType fn) : hitFn_(fn) {}

  bool wantHit() 
  {
    return hitFn_(getCards());
  }

  hitFnType hitFn_;
};
```

Comment: To notice performance difference (virtual vs non-virtual), you need to call the method in question several millions times per second. Because your class is called "CardPlayer", you're not doing anything like that. Which means you're wasting time on premature optimization.

Comment: `CardPlayer` has no other virtual methods, so there is no need to add a virtual dtor. No virtual methods means no polymorphic behavior. What are you getting out of inheritance that you can't get out of making `CardPlayer` a data member of `BlackJackPlayer` instead?

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid the virtual destructor and hence adding a vtbl to the class in your case. You can protect the class from being deleted through the base class pointer, so it seems that, without having any other virtual methods, it would be a premature pessimisation :)

Also, having one more pointer per instance (the vtbl) can add up in large projects. Performance is often depending on memory access and thus you should keep the object size as small as possible and also your memory access patterns as local as possible. The vtbl will be in a different memory location and in the worst case, you ask the processor to read another cache line just to delete an object.

To answer the other question you had: Only virtual methods are routed via the vtbl, all non-virtual calls are uneffected.

Comment: "unaffected"? 8-) -- although I agree that he can *hide* the destructor (make it protected) so that way it cannot be called directly, if you want to use smart pointers, it won't work well.

Answer (score 0):

To look at it from the other direction, if you are assuming you will never call delete on a base class, there is no need to make the destructor virtual, and hiding the base class destructor is a good way to enforce your assumption.

Regarding simply making your destructor virtual, as soon as you declare any method virtual, that class will automatically be given a vtable, which can increase the memory footprint of the class. Only the virtual functions will incur  a vtable lookup. However, both the extra memory ( a single pointer ) and the lookup have minimal performance costs, so you typically would not have to worry about it except in the most performance critical applications.

Answer (score 0):

Making the destructor protected means that it can't be invoked via a base class pointer or reference, which means there's no strong need for it to be virtual.

In general, only public methods or methods that are called by other methods in the base class need to be virtual.  Protected methods need only be virtual if they're called from other methods in the class.